# Getting `Error filling reportError executing sql statement` with MySQL

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

i am using jasper reports with laravel in my project everything works fine.

I have a report working on localhost with no errors when I try the output command in the console with jasper starter.

The problem is, the same report on the server CentOS 6.8 is throwing an error in the ssh terminal using jasper starter :
Error filling reportError executing sql statement for : "report name"

But no error on localhost, and the same database is on the server.

Any idea ?

QUERY :

```
 SELECT
     *,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_BRANCHID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_BRANCHID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTCODE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTCODE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTDESCRIPTION` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTDESCRIPTION,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SUPPLIERID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SUPPLIERID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_UNITCOST` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_UNITCOST,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_LOCATIONID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_LOCATIONID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_GROUPID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_GROUPID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_INVADJUSTMENT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_INVADJUSTMENT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_AVERAGECOST` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_AVERAGECOST,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SELLINGPRICE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SELLINGPRICE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SALESITEM` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SALESITEM,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SHOWINREPORT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SHOWINREPORT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_BUIYINGFORMAT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_BUIYINGFORMAT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_QTYINBUIYINGFORMAT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_QTYINBUIYINGFORMAT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_INVENTORYFORMAT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_INVENTORYFORMAT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_QTYINVENTORYFORMAT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_QTYINVENTORYFORMAT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_USAGEFORMAT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_USAGEFORMAT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_DISCOUNTINUED` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_DISCOUNTINUED,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_OTHERCOST` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_OTHERCOST,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SHIPPINGCOST` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SHIPPINGCOST,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_CUSTOMSCOST` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_CUSTOMSCOST,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_BARCODE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_BARCODE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PIC` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PIC,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_EXPNO` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_EXPNO,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SERNO` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SERNO,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODIDBRANCHID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PRODIDBRANCHID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SP1` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SP1,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SP2` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SP2,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SP3` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SP3,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SP4` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SP4,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PACKINGF` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PACKINGF,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_OTHERDESCRIPTION` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_OTHERDESCRIPTION,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SUPPORTCOLOR` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SUPPORTCOLOR,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SUPPORTSIZE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SUPPORTSIZE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SUPPORTSERIALNUMBER` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SUPPORTSERIALNUMBER,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SUPPORTEXPIRYDATE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SUPPORTEXPIRYDATE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_INCLDAILYADJ` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_INCLDAILYADJ,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_INCLWEEKLADJ` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_INCLWEEKLADJ,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_QTYFORRECIPE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_QTYFORRECIPE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PTYPE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PTYPE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTIONLOCATION` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTIONLOCATION,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SHELFLIFEIND` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SHELFLIFEIND,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_TEXTID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_TEXTID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTIONLEADTIMEF` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTIONLEADTIMEF,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTIONLEADTIMET` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTIONLEADTIMET,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_MAXPRODUCTIONQTY` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_MAXPRODUCTIONQTY,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_SP5` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_SP5,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_TAX1` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_TAX1,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_TAX2` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_TAX2,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_TAX3` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_TAX3,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_TAX4` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_TAX4,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_TAX5` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_TAX5,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_DISCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_DISCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_EXPIRYSALE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_EXPIRYSALE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_NETWEIGHT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_NETWEIGHT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_GROSSWEIGHT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_GROSSWEIGHT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRICEVAR` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PRICEVAR,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_BARCODE2` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_BARCODE2,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_BARCODENATIVE` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_BARCODENATIVE,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_CALUSAGEFORM` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_CALUSAGEFORM,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_CALORIESINITEM` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_CALORIESINITEM,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_CALQTYPERUF` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_CALQTYPERUF,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PICRECEPIE1` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PICRECEPIE1,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PICRECEPIE2` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_PICRECEPIE2,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_MASTERITEM` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_MASTERITEM,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_LINKTOMASTERITEM` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_LINKTOMASTERITEM,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_BRAND_ID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventoryitems_BRAND_ID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_GROUPID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_GROUPID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_BRANCHID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_BRANCHID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_GROUPNAME` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_GROUPNAME,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_DIVISIONID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_DIVISIONID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_ASSETACCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_ASSETACCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_REVENUEACCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_REVENUEACCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_EXPENSEACCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_EXPENSEACCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_TAX1` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_TAX1,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_TAX2` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_TAX2,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_TAX3` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_TAX3,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_MARKUP` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_MARKUP,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_STOCKVARIATIONACC` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_STOCKVARIATIONACC,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_OTHERDESC` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_OTHERDESC,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_TAX4` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_TAX4,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_TAX5` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_TAX5,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_DISCACC` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_DISCACC,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_BRAND_ID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorygroups_BRAND_ID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorydivisions_DIVISIONID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorydivisions_DIVISIONID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorydivisions_DIVISIONNAME` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorydivisions_DIVISIONNAME,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorydivisions_CATEGORYID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorydivisions_CATEGORYID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorydivisions_BRANCHID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorydivisions_BRANCHID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorydivisions_BRAND_ID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorydivisions_BRAND_ID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_CATEGORYID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_CATEGORYID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_CATEGORYNAME` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_CATEGORYNAME,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_MENUID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_MENUID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_BRANCHID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_BRANCHID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_CATEGORYLINKID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_CATEGORYLINKID,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_PURCHASE_ACCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_PURCHASE_ACCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_WASTAGE_ACCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_WASTAGE_ACCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_ADJUSTMENT_ACCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_ADJUSTMENT_ACCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_EMPLOYEESMEALS_ACCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_EMPLOYEESMEALS_ACCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_FREEITEMS_ACCOUNT` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_FREEITEMS_ACCOUNT,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_BRAND_ID` AS invitemcatdivgrp_id_inventorycateg_BRAND_ID,
     id_units.`UNITID` AS id_units_UNITID,
     id_units.`BRANCHID` AS id_units_BRANCHID,
     id_units.`UNITNAME` AS id_units_UNITNAME,
     id_units.`BRAND_ID` AS id_units_BRAND_ID,
     gc_branch.`BRANCHID` AS gc_branch_BRANCHID,
     gc_branch.`BRAND_ID` AS gc_branch_BRAND_ID,
     gc_branch.`OMEGA_CUSTID` AS gc_branch_OMEGA_CUSTID,
     gc_branch.`BARANCHNAME` AS gc_branch_BARANCHNAME,
     gc_branch.`MAINCURRENCY` AS gc_branch_MAINCURRENCY,
     gc_branch.`SECONDCURRENCY` AS gc_branch_SECONDCURRENCY,
     gc_branch.`STREET` AS gc_branch_STREET,
     gc_branch.`CITY` AS gc_branch_CITY,
     gc_branch.`STATE` AS gc_branch_STATE,
     gc_branch.`ZIPCODE` AS gc_branch_ZIPCODE,
     gc_branch.`PHONE1` AS gc_branch_PHONE1,
     gc_branch.`PHONE2` AS gc_branch_PHONE2,
     gc_branch.`PHONE3` AS gc_branch_PHONE3,
     gc_branch.`PHONE4` AS gc_branch_PHONE4,
     gc_branch.`FAX` AS gc_branch_FAX,
     gc_branch.`FEDID` AS gc_branch_FEDID,
     gc_branch.`FISCALSTART` AS gc_branch_FISCALSTART,
     gc_branch.`FISCALEND` AS gc_branch_FISCALEND,
     gc_branch.`LASTENDOFDAY` AS gc_branch_LASTENDOFDAY,
     gc_branch.`ADVERTONINVOICE` AS gc_branch_ADVERTONINVOICE,
     gc_branch.`MESSAGEONPOS1` AS gc_branch_MESSAGEONPOS1,
     gc_branch.`MESSAGEONPOS2` AS gc_branch_MESSAGEONPOS2,
     gc_branch.`MESSAGEONPOS3` AS gc_branch_MESSAGEONPOS3,
     gc_branch.`MESSAGEONPOS4` AS gc_branch_MESSAGEONPOS4,
     gc_branch.`MESSAGEONPOS5` AS gc_branch_MESSAGEONPOS5,
     gc_branch.`PIC` AS gc_branch_PIC,
     gc_branch.`LOCALOFFICEID` AS gc_branch_LOCALOFFICEID,
     gc_branch.`ACCOUNTINGDEPT` AS gc_branch_ACCOUNTINGDEPT,
     gc_branch.`HOSTSTRING` AS gc_branch_HOSTSTRING,
     gc_branch.`FRANCHISEE` AS gc_branch_FRANCHISEE,
     gc_branch.`SALESPRICE` AS gc_branch_SALESPRICE,
     gc_branch.`CUSTOMERID` AS gc_branch_CUSTOMERID,
     gc_branch.`IPADDRESS` AS gc_branch_IPADDRESS,
     gc_branch.`PORT` AS gc_branch_PORT,
     gc_branch.`EMAIL` AS gc_branch_EMAIL,
     gc_branch.`COUNTRY_ID` AS gc_branch_COUNTRY_ID,
     id_locations.`LOCATIONID` AS id_locations_LOCATIONID,
     id_locations.`BRANCHID` AS id_locations_BRANCHID,
     id_locations.`LOCATIONDESCRIPTION` AS id_locations_LOCATIONDESCRIPTION,
     id_locations.`FORBRANCH` AS id_locations_FORBRANCH,
     id_locations.`ACCDEPT` AS id_locations_ACCDEPT,
     id_locations.`BRAND_ID` AS id_locations_BRAND_ID,
     it_requisitions.`REQBRANCHID` AS it_requisitions_REQBRANCHID,
     it_requisitions.`REQID` AS it_requisitions_REQID,
     it_requisitions.`BRANCHID` AS it_requisitions_BRANCHID,
     it_requisitions.`USERID` AS it_requisitions_USERID,
     it_requisitions.`REQDATE` AS it_requisitions_REQDATE,
     it_requisitions.`PRDID` AS it_requisitions_PRDID,
     it_requisitions.`QTY` AS it_requisitions_QTY,
     it_requisitions.`SOURCE` AS it_requisitions_SOURCE,
     it_requisitions.`DESTINATION` AS it_requisitions_DESTINATION,
     it_requisitions.`EXP` AS it_requisitions_EXP,
     it_requisitions.`REQNO` AS it_requisitions_REQNO,
     it_requisitions.`OLDQTY` AS it_requisitions_OLDQTY,
     it_requisitions.`FROMBRANCH` AS it_requisitions_FROMBRANCH,
     it_requisitions.`TOBRANCH` AS it_requisitions_TOBRANCH,
     it_requisitions.`TRANSFERED` AS it_requisitions_TRANSFERED,
     it_requisitions.`FILENUMBER` AS it_requisitions_FILENUMBER,
     it_requisitions.`FILEBRANCHID` AS it_requisitions_FILEBRANCHID,
     it_requisitions.`EXPORTED` AS it_requisitions_EXPORTED,
     it_requisitions.`AVGCOST` AS it_requisitions_AVGCOST,
     it_requisitions.`COST` AS it_requisitions_COST,
     it_requisitions.`RECEIVED` AS it_requisitions_RECEIVED,
     it_requisitions.`BRAND_ID` AS it_requisitions_BRAND_ID,
     gc_branch_A.`BRANCHID` AS gc_branch_A_BRANCHID,
     gc_branch_A.`BRAND_ID` AS gc_branch_A_BRAND_ID,
     gc_branch_A.`OMEGA_CUSTID` AS gc_branch_A_OMEGA_CUSTID,
     gc_branch_A.`BARANCHNAME` AS gc_branch_A_BARANCHNAME,
     gc_branch_A.`MAINCURRENCY` AS gc_branch_A_MAINCURRENCY,
     gc_branch_A.`SECONDCURRENCY` AS gc_branch_A_SECONDCURRENCY,
     gc_branch_A.`STREET` AS gc_branch_A_STREET,
     gc_branch_A.`CITY` AS gc_branch_A_CITY,
     gc_branch_A.`STATE` AS gc_branch_A_STATE,
     gc_branch_A.`ZIPCODE` AS gc_branch_A_ZIPCODE,
     gc_branch_A.`PHONE1` AS gc_branch_A_PHONE1,
     gc_branch_A.`PHONE2` AS gc_branch_A_PHONE2,
     gc_branch_A.`PHONE3` AS gc_branch_A_PHONE3,
     gc_branch_A.`PHONE4` AS gc_branch_A_PHONE4,
     gc_branch_A.`FAX` AS gc_branch_A_FAX,
     gc_branch_A.`FEDID` AS gc_branch_A_FEDID,
     gc_branch_A.`FISCALSTART` AS gc_branch_A_FISCALSTART,
     gc_branch_A.`FISCALEND` AS gc_branch_A_FISCALEND,
     gc_branch_A.`LASTENDOFDAY` AS gc_branch_A_LASTENDOFDAY,
     gc_branch_A.`ADVERTONINVOICE` AS gc_branch_A_ADVERTONINVOICE,
     gc_branch_A.`MESSAGEONPOS1` AS gc_branch_A_MESSAGEONPOS1,
     gc_branch_A.`MESSAGEONPOS2` AS gc_branch_A_MESSAGEONPOS2,
     gc_branch_A.`MESSAGEONPOS3` AS gc_branch_A_MESSAGEONPOS3,
     gc_branch_A.`MESSAGEONPOS4` AS gc_branch_A_MESSAGEONPOS4,
     gc_branch_A.`MESSAGEONPOS5` AS gc_branch_A_MESSAGEONPOS5,
     gc_branch_A.`PIC` AS gc_branch_A_PIC,
     gc_branch_A.`LOCALOFFICEID` AS gc_branch_A_LOCALOFFICEID,
     gc_branch_A.`ACCOUNTINGDEPT` AS gc_branch_A_ACCOUNTINGDEPT,
     gc_branch_A.`HOSTSTRING` AS gc_branch_A_HOSTSTRING,
     gc_branch_A.`FRANCHISEE` AS gc_branch_A_FRANCHISEE,
     gc_branch_A.`SALESPRICE` AS gc_branch_A_SALESPRICE,
     gc_branch_A.`CUSTOMERID` AS gc_branch_A_CUSTOMERID,
     gc_branch_A.`IPADDRESS` AS gc_branch_A_IPADDRESS,
     gc_branch_A.`PORT` AS gc_branch_A_PORT,
     gc_branch_A.`EMAIL` AS gc_branch_A_EMAIL,
     gc_branch_A.`COUNTRY_ID` AS gc_branch_A_COUNTRY_ID,
     gc_branch_B.`BRANCHID` AS gc_branch_B_BRANCHID,
     gc_branch_B.`BRAND_ID` AS gc_branch_B_BRAND_ID,
     gc_branch_B.`OMEGA_CUSTID` AS gc_branch_B_OMEGA_CUSTID,
     gc_branch_B.`BARANCHNAME` AS gc_branch_B_BARANCHNAME,
     gc_branch_B.`MAINCURRENCY` AS gc_branch_B_MAINCURRENCY,
     gc_branch_B.`SECONDCURRENCY` AS gc_branch_B_SECONDCURRENCY,
     gc_branch_B.`STREET` AS gc_branch_B_STREET,
     gc_branch_B.`CITY` AS gc_branch_B_CITY,
     gc_branch_B.`STATE` AS gc_branch_B_STATE,
     gc_branch_B.`ZIPCODE` AS gc_branch_B_ZIPCODE,
     gc_branch_B.`PHONE1` AS gc_branch_B_PHONE1,
     gc_branch_B.`PHONE2` AS gc_branch_B_PHONE2,
     gc_branch_B.`PHONE3` AS gc_branch_B_PHONE3,
     gc_branch_B.`PHONE4` AS gc_branch_B_PHONE4,
     gc_branch_B.`FAX` AS gc_branch_B_FAX,
     gc_branch_B.`FEDID` AS gc_branch_B_FEDID,
     gc_branch_B.`FISCALSTART` AS gc_branch_B_FISCALSTART,
     gc_branch_B.`FISCALEND` AS gc_branch_B_FISCALEND,
     gc_branch_B.`LASTENDOFDAY` AS gc_branch_B_LASTENDOFDAY,
     gc_branch_B.`ADVERTONINVOICE` AS gc_branch_B_ADVERTONINVOICE,
     gc_branch_B.`MESSAGEONPOS1` AS gc_branch_B_MESSAGEONPOS1,
     gc_branch_B.`MESSAGEONPOS2` AS gc_branch_B_MESSAGEONPOS2,
     gc_branch_B.`MESSAGEONPOS3` AS gc_branch_B_MESSAGEONPOS3,
     gc_branch_B.`MESSAGEONPOS4` AS gc_branch_B_MESSAGEONPOS4,
     gc_branch_B.`MESSAGEONPOS5` AS gc_branch_B_MESSAGEONPOS5,
     gc_branch_B.`PIC` AS gc_branch_B_PIC,
     gc_branch_B.`LOCALOFFICEID` AS gc_branch_B_LOCALOFFICEID,
     gc_branch_B.`ACCOUNTINGDEPT` AS gc_branch_B_ACCOUNTINGDEPT,
     gc_branch_B.`HOSTSTRING` AS gc_branch_B_HOSTSTRING,
     gc_branch_B.`FRANCHISEE` AS gc_branch_B_FRANCHISEE,
     gc_branch_B.`SALESPRICE` AS gc_branch_B_SALESPRICE,
     gc_branch_B.`CUSTOMERID` AS gc_branch_B_CUSTOMERID,
     gc_branch_B.`IPADDRESS` AS gc_branch_B_IPADDRESS,
     gc_branch_B.`PORT` AS gc_branch_B_PORT,
     gc_branch_B.`EMAIL` AS gc_branch_B_EMAIL,
     gc_branch_B.`COUNTRY_ID` AS gc_branch_B_COUNTRY_ID,
     id_locations_A.`LOCATIONID` AS id_locations_A_LOCATIONID,
     id_locations_A.`BRANCHID` AS id_locations_A_BRANCHID,
     id_locations_A.`LOCATIONDESCRIPTION` AS id_locations_A_LOCATIONDESCRIPTION,
     id_locations_A.`FORBRANCH` AS id_locations_A_FORBRANCH,
     id_locations_A.`ACCDEPT` AS id_locations_A_ACCDEPT,
     id_locations_A.`BRAND_ID` AS id_locations_A_BRAND_ID
FROM
     `id_units` id_units INNER JOIN `invitemcatdivgrp` invitemcatdivgrp ON id_units.`UNITID` = invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_INVENTORYFORMAT`
     AND id_units.`BRAND_ID` = invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_BRAND_ID`
     INNER JOIN `gc_branch` gc_branch ON id_units.`BRANCHID` = gc_branch.`BRANCHID`
     INNER JOIN `gc_branch` gc_branch_B ON id_units.`BRANCHID` = gc_branch_B.`BRANCHID`
     AND invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_BRAND_ID` = gc_branch_B.`BRAND_ID`
     INNER JOIN `it_requisitions` it_requisitions ON gc_branch_B.`BRANCHID` = it_requisitions.`BRANCHID`
     INNER JOIN `id_locations` id_locations ON gc_branch_B.`BRAND_ID` = id_locations.`BRAND_ID`
     AND it_requisitions.`SOURCE` = id_locations.`LOCATIONID`
     AND id_locations.`FORBRANCH` = it_requisitions.`FROMBRANCH`
     AND invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_BRAND_ID` = id_locations.`BRAND_ID`
     INNER JOIN `gc_branch` gc_branch_A ON id_locations.`BRAND_ID` = gc_branch_A.`BRAND_ID`
     INNER JOIN `id_locations` id_locations_A ON id_locations.`BRAND_ID` = id_locations_A.`BRAND_ID`
     AND it_requisitions.`DESTINATION` = id_locations_A.`LOCATIONID`
     AND id_locations_A.`FORBRANCH` = it_requisitions.`TOBRANCH`
     AND it_requisitions.`FROMBRANCH` = gc_branch_A.`BRANCHID`
     AND invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_BRAND_ID` = it_requisitions.`BRAND_ID`
     AND invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTID` = it_requisitions.`PRDID`
     AND gc_branch.`BRANCHID` = it_requisitions.`BRANCHID`
     AND invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_BRAND_ID` = gc_branch.`BRAND_ID`

WHERE
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_BRAND_ID` = $P{Brandid} and
     it_requisitions.`REQDATE`  >= $P{FromDate} and  it_requisitions.`REQDATE` <=  $P{ToDate} and

(CASE WHEN $P{Frombranchid} > 0
    THEN gc_branch_A.`BRANCHID` >= $P{Frombranchid}
    ELSE IT_REQUISITIONS.`FROMBRANCH` = gc_branch_A.`BRANCHID`
END)

ORDER BY
     gc_branch.`BARANCHNAME` ASC,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorycateg_CATEGORYNAME` ASC,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorydivisions_DIVISIONNAME` ASC,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventorygroups_GROUPNAME` ASC,
     it_requisitions.`REQDATE` ASC,
     it_requisitions.`SOURCE` ASC,
     it_requisitions.`DESTINATION` ASC,
     invitemcatdivgrp.`id_inventoryitems_PRODUCTDESCRIPTION` ASC
```

Comment: Do you have more info about error (from logs)?

Comment: no, that's the problem, only : error filling reportError executing SQL statement for : report1.

Comment: Probably something wrong with passing parameters to report. You can try to add *textField* with parameters from query to check it

Comment: ok i will try to pass static textfields to check if from parameters

Comment: I edited the post, can u check my query ? the "case" statement, on localhost everything fine

Comment: `it_requisitions.REQDATE  >= $P{FromDate}` - Is it working ok? What DB are you using?

Comment: yes it's working, am sending the date as string in url from the web project and it's working fine locally, I removed the case statements, the report working fine now, can u check them please ?

Comment: What is a type of `it_requisitions.REQDATE`? What is DB?

Comment: the type in mysql is date, but comparing in report with string, that's working  fine, the problem is after the date, when i removed the cases, the report is working

Comment: @AlexK I removed step by step case after case, i left only 1 "case" statement" the report crashed again, without  "case" statement the report's working

Comment: Did you check parameters from CASES?

Comment: yes, all parameters are good, if there's parameter missing or something the report would crash returning that error (tested before), I'm not sure if the case statement is correct, the way i typed it (CASE ...

Comment: I checked field type compairing to the parameter type, nothing ... the reports is not accepting the case statement

Comment: @AlexK does the mysql version or something is not accepting the "CASE WHEN ELSE" ?

Comment: Did you check the query from mysql console (after replacing parameter with const)?

Comment: @AlexK yes, I tried it, and it's working when i replaced parameters with static

Comment: Which case is invalid? You should [simplify](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40277329/edit) query in the post

Comment: @AlexK  code updated

Comment: @AlexK I tried static values" on the server" too, still the same problem, so the prob is not from params, it's from the CASE syntax i dnt know why

Comment: I think it is better for you to fix post's title and the body to attract attention on MySQL experts :)

Comment: @AlexK probem solved, I don't know why the mysql workbench didn't throw error that I have 2 tables with capital letters, while the tables are not capita, when i tried the query in phpmyadmin, it returns the error, and i fixed it ), the local database was accepting but the online 1 was crashing because of the capital letters.  Thank you bro

Comment: Congratulations! You are welcome :)